# MasterPage .FindControl in Class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to find a control, an image button to be exact, in master page access from content pages. Following is the master page html code:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="navLeft">
        <br />           
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnMooring" runat="server" 
            Height="60px" ImageUrl="~/Item/RibbonIcon/Dashboard.png" />
        <br />
    </div>
    <div class="navTop">            
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div class="divider">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I success in doing so when i put the following code in the content page aspx.cs file

```
    string validMooring = "";

    comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.StructureCurrent", conn);
    conn.Open();
    reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       validMooring = reader["StructureMooring"].ToString();
    }

    switch (validMooring)
    {
        case "YES":
            (Page.Master.FindControl("imgbtnMooring") as ImageButton).Enabled = true;
            (Page.Master.FindControl("imgbtnMooring") as ImageButton).ImageUrl = "~/Item/RibbonIcon/Dashboard.png";
            break;
        case "NO":
            (Page.Master.FindControl("imgbtnMooring") as ImageButton).Enabled = false;
            (Page.Master.FindControl("imgbtnMooring") as ImageButton).ImageUrl = "~/Item/RibbonIcon - Grey/DashboardGrey.png";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Right now I try to make a class file named GeneralClass so that above code can be access in any content pages. The sql command is just to extract the YES/NO value from server, so I think it something that can be ignore for my problem.

Following is the code in the GeneralClass class file:

```
    MasterPage masterPage = new MasterPage();
    masterPage.MasterPageFile = "~/GeneralLayout.master";

    string validMooring = "";

    comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.StructureCurrent", conn);
    conn.Open();
    reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        validMooring = reader["StructureMooring"].ToString();
    }

    switch (validMooring)
    {
        case "YES":
            (masterPage.FindControl("imgbtnMooring") as ImageButton).Enabled = true;
            (masterPage.FindControl("imgbtnMooring") as ImageButton).ImageUrl = "~/Item/RibbonIcon/Dashboard.png";
            break;
        case "NO":
            (masterPage.FindControl("imgbtnMooring") as ImageButton).Enabled = false;
            (masterPage.FindControl("imgbtnMooring") as ImageButton).ImageUrl = "~/Item/RibbonIcon - Grey/DashboardGrey.png";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

But somehow the line (masterPage.FindControl("imgbtnMooring") as ImageButton) return null value.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found away to do the thing that i want which is to find the control on master page and by using the YES/NO value from server to enabled/disabled the button. Following is the code I use. Unlike in my question in which I post code for one image button, I will post code for 2 image button instead for better understanding. This code is for my 'GeneralClass' class file

```
public void validNavLeft()
{
    string validHull = "", validMooring = "";

    comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.StructureCurrent", conn);
    conn.Open();
    reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        validHull = reader["StructureHull"].ToString();
        validMooring = reader["StructureMooring"].ToString();
    }

    var pageHandler = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
    Control ctrlHull = ((Page)pageHandler).Master.FindControl("imgbtnHull");
    ImageButton imgBtnHull = (ImageButton)ctrlHull;
    Control ctrlMooring = ((Page)pageHandler).Master.FindControl("imgbtnMooring");
    ImageButton imgBtnMooring = (ImageButton)ctrlMooring;

    switch (validHull)
    {
        case "YES":
            imgBtnHull.Enabled = true;
            imgBtnHull.ImageUrl = "~/Item/RibbonIcon/Dashboard.png";
            break;
        case "NO":
            imgBtnHull.Enabled = false;
            imgBtnHull.ImageUrl = "~/Item/RibbonIcon - Grey/DashboardGrey.png";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    switch (validMooring)
    {
        case "YES":
            imgBtnMooring.Enabled = true;
            imgBtnMooring.ImageUrl = "~/Item/RibbonIcon/Dashboard.png";
            break;
        case "NO":
            imgBtnMooring.Enabled = false;
            imgBtnMooring.ImageUrl = "~/Item/RibbonIcon - Grey/DashboardGrey.png";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Page Extension method as I suspect your code is not able to find the controls.

**`Master.cs:`**

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  this.EnableControls(null);
}
```

**Add following NameSpaces in GeneralClass class file:**

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public static void EnableControls(this Page page, ControlCollection ctrl)
{
    if (ctrl == null)
        ctrl = page.Controls;

    string validMooring = "";

    comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.StructureCurrent", conn);
    conn.Open();
    reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      validMooring = reader["StructureMooring"].ToString();
    }

    foreach (Control item in ctrl)
    {
        if (item.Controls.Count > 0)
            EnableControls(page, item.Controls, isEnable);

        if (item.GetType() == typeof(ImageButton))
        {
            switch (validMooring)
            {
              case "YES":
                ((ImageButton)item).Enabled = true;
                ((ImageButton)item).ImageUrl = "~/Item/RibbonIcon/Dashboard.png";
                 break;

              case "NO":
                ((ImageButton)item).Enabled = false;
                ((ImageButton)item).ImageUrl = "~/Item/RibbonIcon - Grey/DashboardGrey.png";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What i mean is, is this wok for multiple image button in which each image button have it own validation like in this case validMooring. From what I can understand from your code it only can be used for multiple image button but have 1 validation.