# Explain to me the function of this line of code

Tags: c#, asp.net

While I was searching for answer to my problem in [MasterPage .FindControl in Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37983174/masterpage-findcontrol-in-class), I stumbled across this solution but what do these lines of code do? Can anyone explain to me?

```
var pageHandler = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
Control ctrlHull = ((Page)pageHandler).Master.FindControl("imgbtnHull");
ImageButton imgBtnHull = (ImageButton)ctrlHull;
```

I'm self-teaching myself C# programming so I have little knowledge about this language.

Comment: What have you self-taught so far?

Comment: Most of the material in this website http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp.html and I also when to 4 days training for basic C# programming using ASP.NET framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of getting NullReference in this line `(ImageButton)ctrlHull` So i suggest you to check for `null` before convert `ctrlHull` as `(ImageButton)`. Let me explain the rest of code:

> The expected action to be performed by this snippet is to find an ImageButton named `imgbtnHull` in the master page of the current page.

This can be achieved with the help of following :

- `HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler` : HttpContext itself is an
  object, you can access the current serving page from
  [`HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.currenthandler(v=vs.110).aspx) since the Page implements
  *IHttpHandler*
- The second line will give you the [Master Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) from which the current page is inherited. Then `.FindControl` Searches the current naming container for a server control with the specified id parameter. which will return The specified control, or null if the specified control does not exist(Here comes the first point that i have mentioned, the `NullReference`).
- And Finally the code converts the control as an Image button and assigned to `imgBtnHull`.

Here is the modified code:

```
var pageHandler = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
Control ctrlHull = ((Page)pageHandler).Master.FindControl("imgbtnHull");
if(ctrlHull !=null)
{
   ImageButton imgBtnHull = (ImageButton)ctrlHull;
   // Proceed with imgBtnHull 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Fahmieyz : Mark it as accepted if it [useful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

```
// Get the page that is handling the current request.
var pageHandler = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
// Find the control named "imgbtnHull" on the master page.
Control ctrlHull = ((Page)pageHandler).Master.FindControl("imgbtnHull");
// Cast the control to type ImageButton.
ImageButton imgBtnHull = (ImageButton)ctrlHull;
```

So basically, it's grabbing a reference to the ImageButton named "imgbtnHull" that is defined within the current page's Master Page.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.